# Replace rows of strings in dataframe with corresponding words in other dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df which has 1 column

```
     List
 0   What are you trying to achieve
 1   What is your purpose right here
 2   When students don’t have a proper foundation
 3   I am going to DESCRIBE a sunset
```

I have other dataframe df2

which has 2 columns

```
    original       correct
0     are          were
1     sunset       sunrise
2     I            we
3     right        correct
4     is           was
```

I want to replace such words in my df,which occurs in `original` column of my df2
and replace with corresponding words in `correct` column.
and store the new strings in other dataframe `df_new`

Is it possible without using loops and iteration, and only using plain pandas concept?

i.e my `df_new` should contain.

```
     List
 0   What were you trying to achieve
 1   What was your purpose correct here
 2   When students don’t have a proper foundation
 3   we am going to DESCRIBE a sunrise
```

Also this is just a test example,
MY `df` MIGHT CONTAIN millions of rows of string, and so my df2,
What would be the most efficient solution path i can go on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of many possible solutions:

```
In [371]: boundary = r'\b'
     ...:
     ...: df.List.replace((boundary + df2.orignal + boundary).values.tolist(),
     ...:                 df2.correct.values.tolist(),
     ...:                 regex=True)
     ...:
Out[371]:
0                  What were you trying to achieve
1               What was your purpose correct here
2     When students don’t have a proper foundation
3                we am going to DESCRIBE a sunrise
Name: List, dtype: object
```

Comment: `DESCRIBE` is also touched.

Comment: @MaxU for a huge dataset, say million's of rows of strings, and also in df2,
would this be a better solution?

Comment: Another addition, `df['List'].replace({r'\b' + k + r'\b':x for k, x in df2.set_index('orignal').to_dict()['correct'].items()}, regex=True)`

Comment: @JohnGalt Sir, 'mapping' ? Getting error `NameError: name 'mapping' is not defined`

Comment: @JohnGalt yes  figured that :) Thanks